# Create a knn adjacent matrix in Pytorch

Tags: matrix, indexing, pytorch, tensor

In Pytorch, say I have a top-k indexing matrix `P(B,N,k)`, a weight matrix `W(B,N,N)` and a target matrix `A(B,N,N)`, I want to get a adjacent matrix that operates as the following loops:

```
for i in range(B):
     for ii in range(N):
         for j in range(k):
             if weighted:
                 A[i][ii][P[i][ii][j]] = W[i][ii][P[i][ii][j]]
             else:
                 A[i][ii][P[i][ii][j]] = 1
```

How to implement it more efficiently and concisely in **Pytorch**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`torch.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_):

```py
A.scatter_(dim=2, index=P, src=W)  # for the weighted version
A.scatter_(dim=2, index=P, src=torch.ones_like(W))  # for the un-weighted version
```